# xpath in java without reflection

Tags: java, reflection, xpath, jaxb

I have to work a lot with JAXB objects and there is an annoying thing when getting a value. Let's suppose I have got the next XML:

```
...
<a>
   <b>
      <c>1</c>
   </b>
</a>
...
```

In java I can reach the value of the element c as follows:

```
xml.getA().getB().getC()
```

However if the elements are not mandatory then I have to implement many if conditions to check whether or not the element is null.

```
if (xml != null && xml.getA() != null && xml.getA().getB() != null && xml.getA().getB().getC() != null {
   ...
}
```

I would like to use XPath directly on the JAXB objects to avoid writing these horrible if conditions. I know there are some similar tools (e.g. Apache JXPAth) but usually these frameworks use reflection. I don't want to use reflection as it impacts the performance badly.
Unfortunately I cannot imagine any solution without using reflection but perhaps there is one.
Could you help me?
Thanks,
V.

---

I found the org.w3c.dom.Document can be used with XPath but the next question is how could I use org.w3c.dom.Document in an annotated webservice without marshalling it again? (I am a bit worried about marshalling the XML more than necessary) Thanks!

Comment: Reflection is not necessarily slow. Any decent framework that uses reflection properly (that is, caching `java.lang.reflect.*` instances and related info) will give you performance close to the equivalent non-reflective access. Test it before you discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a "good" solution, but if your primary goal is to avoid writing all those if conditions, have you considered just wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch NullPointerException? Performance will suffer in cases where it doesn't exist, and I would say that's not very good use of exceptions, but it would allow for simpler syntax of getting to and using the inner values.